# Django 1.6 Scientific Notation FloatField "Please enter a valid number"

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

I have a FloatField in a forms.Form class that should accept scientific notation (e.g. 9e-08).  In Django 1.6.x this field does not validate and returns "Please enter a valid number".  In Django 1.5.x the field raises no such exception and the form validates.

Field in question:

```
vapor_pressure = forms.FloatField(
        label='Vapor Pressure',
        initial=9e-8
)
```

Any hints as to what is causing Django 1.6.x to raise an exception on my field?

I have overridden the is_valid() method in my Form class to log the is_valid() result, and that is not where Django raises the exception:

```
def is_valid(self):
    #Run validation
    valid = super(ModelInp, self).is_valid()
    print valid
    if not valid:
        print "MODEL NOT VALID"
        return True
    else:
        print "MODEL VALID"
        return True
```

Comment: Can you post the traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're seeing this because Django 1.6 added [HTML5 input types](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/) to their forms. (Check the generated form field for `type="number"`.) So it is the browser that is checking and rejecting your value, presumably because it doesn't recognize scientific notation.

If my guess is right, the simple solution is just to customize your form and [change the widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/widgets/) for that field to a regular `TextInput`. Another possible option is to add the `novalidate` attribute to your form in the template.

For more discussion see [this thread on django-developers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/TGwABHUPrw8).

Comment: This was the issue, which seems to be a browser/HTML5 issue and not a Django issue.  I chose to turn off the client/browser form validation using: <button formnovalidate="formnovalidate" class="input_button">Submit</button>

Comment: Also note that jQuery Validation plugin was interfering with the HTML5 input types, not allowing the Scientific Notation to be submitted